# How to adjust the height of the thumb in the scrollbar?

Tags: android, layout, include, scrollbar

Using a layout that has all of the scrollbar elements on it (track, thumb, up and down arrows), I'm trying to make a smaller, customized scrollbar that is included with the "include" tag (see reference XML and code below) into all layouts that need a scrollbar. I have a smallScrollbar.class that extends View and implements ScrollingView in order to use computeVerticalScrollRange/Offset/Extent methods to modify the scrollbar in order for it to be accurate to the contents are being scrolled through. In order to do that, however, the class needs  the View it's getting height values from, and the scrollbar that is assigned *to that View*, so that the correct View/scrollbar is modified to fit the given screen and contents.

small_scrollbar.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/smallScrollbar"
android:layout_width="75dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#00232F3E">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/scrolltrack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#00232F3E"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_track_bmp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrolluparrow" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/scrollthumb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_thumb_bmp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrolluparrow" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/scrolluparrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="#00232F3E"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_arrow_up"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrolltrack"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/scrolldownarrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:background="#003E2323"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_arrow_down"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrolltrack" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

smallScrollbar() class:

```
public class smallScrollbar extends View implements ScrollingView {

public int thumbLength;
private int trackLength;
private int totalLength;
private View importedView;
private ConstraintLayout importedScrollbar;

@Override
public int computeHorizontalScrollRange() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int computeHorizontalScrollOffset() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int computeHorizontalScrollExtent() {
    return 0;
}

public int computeVerticalScrollRange() {
    if (this.trackLength == -1)
    {
        this.trackLength = this.importedScrollbar.findViewById(R.id.scrolltrack).getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    return this.trackLength;
}

public int computeVerticalScrollOffset() {
    this.getHeights(importedView);
    int highestVisiblePixel = super.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
    return this.computeScrollOffset(highestVisiblePixel);
}

private final int computeScrollOffset(int highestVisiblePixel) {
    int undrawnViewPortion = this.totalLength - this.trackLength;
    int scrollAmountRemaining = undrawnViewPortion - highestVisiblePixel;
    return undrawnViewPortion == scrollAmountRemaining ? 0 : (scrollAmountRemaining > 0 ? Math.round((float) (this.trackLength - this.thumbLength) / ((float) undrawnViewPortion / (float) highestVisiblePixel)) : this.trackLength - this.thumbLength);
}

public int computeVerticalScrollExtent() {
    return this.thumbLength;
}

private final void getHeights(View view) {
    if (this.totalLength == -1) {
        int normalHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(this.getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        this.totalLength = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(this.getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(normalHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    }
}

public final int dpToPx(int dp) {
    float input = (float) dp;
    Resources viewRes = this.getResources();
    return Math.round(input * viewRes.getDisplayMetrics().density);
}

public smallScrollbar(@NotNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, View viewIn, ConstraintLayout scrollbarLayout) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.importedView = viewIn;
    this.importedScrollbar = scrollbarLayout;
    this.trackLength = -1;
    this.totalLength = -1;
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.smallScrollbar);
    this.thumbLength = this.dpToPx((int) typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.smallScrollbar_thumbLength, 64.0F));
    typedArray.recycle();
}

public smallScrollbar(@NotNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, View viewIn, ConstraintLayout scrollbarLayout) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.trackLength = -1;
    this.totalLength = -1;
    this.importedView = viewIn;
    this.importedScrollbar = scrollbarLayout;
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.smallScrollbar);
    this.thumbLength = this.dpToPx((int) typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.smallScrollbar_thumbLength, 64.0F));
    typedArray.recycle();
}
}
```

I have the methods mentioned before (computing vertical values for scrolling), as well as some constructors I've written in order to get the specific scrollbar we need, and the specific view it's sitting in.

Now... my problem. I've set this all up, I have the scrollbar included in the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/settingsFragLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/exampleColor"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/settingsRecyclerView"
        style="@style/settingsFragmentViewStyle"
        android:background="@color/exampleColor"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb"
        android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/ic_scroll_track_bmp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragScrollbar"
        layout="@layout/small_scrollbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/settingsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:background="@color/cardDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/settingsRecyclerView" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameContainerSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/exampleColor"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in the class I've added it to, I've instantiated a scrollbar:

```
smallScrollbar settingsScrollbar = new smallScrollbar(context, null, rv, rootView.findViewById(R.id.settingsFragScrollbar));
```

The "rv" View is the RecyclerView that needs to be scrolled; the rootView is the inflater.inflate() of this particular classs' xml (linked above).

However, when I access the layout of the class and try to add a value for "thumbLength" into it, it doesn't work; it's as if the attribute doesn't exist. It does, however, in my attrs.xml file:

```
<declare-styleable name="smallScrollbar">
    <attr name="thumbLength" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

I'm sure this is because the original code implementation was an extension of the RecyclerView, and the attribute not showing up or working is associated with the fact that it's no longer an extended RecyclerView, but a class that imports a view and the layout of the scrollbar (which is the same every time)... which from what I can understand means this class has no access to the thumbLength attribute even though it extends View and implements ScrollingView. I tried setting the height of the thumb during the constructor call instead, but I can't seem to modify the height of the ImageView either, only the minimum height can be set. I'm completely at a loss as to how I could resize this thumb now, and although there's methods for computing the vertical range/extent/offset defined and code in place, it doesn't seem to have any effect on the scrollbar thumb. Does anyone know how I would be able to access the "thumbLength" attribute so I can adjust the size of the thumb here, or just a way to adjust the thumb's size relative to the track's fixed height and the contents it is scrolling? The logic is all here, but for some reason it's not having an effect.

Comment: Are you assigning ``settingsScrollbar`` anywhere? That's what's null according to the stacktrace

Comment: I do have it initialized in the class, but I hadn't fully assigned it using a constructor yet within onCreateView() or anything yet. I'll do that first thing tomorrow and see what happens with it.

Comment: @cactustictacs I've fixed the null exception by fully constructing the smallScrollbar() class, but now I'm having difficulty adjusting the size of the thumb in the scrollbar although an attribute for the class was defined and worked for it beforehand when it was extending RecyclerView instead of just View. Is that the reason I lost access to that attribute, or is it something else?

Comment: When you assign ``settingsScrollbar`` by constructing one in code, you're passing ``null`` for your attrs parameter, so there's no value for ``thumbLength``. Honestly I'm not 100% on what you're trying to do, do you want to adjust the height of the thumb that's part of the ``RecyclerView``? Or are you trying to add a separate view that acts as a scrollbar?

Comment: I am trying to add a separate view that acts as a scrollbar for the view that it's been placed in. The built-in scrollbar is too close to the view it's attached to, and due to how the height of the scrollbar is calculated, it's too tall. The overall goal is positioning the scrollbar wherever I'd like it (although mostly on the far right side of each view), decrease its overall size significantly, and also being able to adjust the thumb's size so the scrollbar is accurate to the contents it is scrolling.

Comment: Ok, when you just construct a ``View`` in code like that, you're not actually adding it to the layout anywhere, so it's not part of the UI. Generally when you create a custom view, you add that to an XML layout file, and that's where you can add its ``styleable`` attributes. You haven't posted your ``small_scrollbar.xml`` layout that you're ``include``ing - I'm assuming you have a ``SmallScrollbar`` in there, but as far as I'm aware the inflater can't actually create one because it's not using one of the standard ``View`` constructor signatures. And you'd need to ``findViewById`` it

Comment: I don't have time to do a full answer, but the way I'd typically do a custom view like this: 1) extend ``FrameLayout`` with the standard constructors, 2) when initialising get a ``LayoutInflater`` from the ``context`` passed in and inflate your XML (the one you're `include`ing I guess) using ``this`` as the parent and ``attachToRoot = true``, 3) do your `findById` stuff in your view to grab whatever references you need (no need to pass them in like you're doing), and 4) just add it to your main layout as a widget and add your custom attributes. A custom view like that should be self-contained

Comment: Thank you for the information you've provided me here, I very much appreciate your efforts to help; I've also put the small_scrollbar.xml into this question so that is referenceable. Where I am still confused is how inflating the scrollbar's layout is much different from using 'include' to bring it into the view, and how that would help me modify the thumb's size relative to the view. How does the scrollbar thumb know how big the view is if the view isn't fed into the class?

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on "compound views" so you get a sense of how this stuff generally works. You want to create a `View` that you just add to your layout XML as a single component, with any attributes it needs - same as a ``Button``, a ``Checkbox`` etc. The View itself takes care of its contents, inflating a layout if necessary, talking to any views in that layout (like changing their attributes) and so on. What you're doing right now is throwing all the UI pieces into your main layout and then creating a view component (that's not even displayed) and trying to wire it all up externally

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into compound views and do some more research. I truly appreciate you giving me all of this information; I've been trying to deal with this for months, and this has been more helpful than all the searching I did for something about this. While I've not gotten a direct solution, I have gotten a few ideas as to how I can try to figure out a solution. Cheers!